# Exporta tabla de una base de datos desde PHP con formato SQL

Tags: php, sql, importación

Saludos he intentado exportar una tabla de una base de datos  desde PHP pero creo que no estoy usando la extensión correcta. Por favor explíquenme y de antemano gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$bd_host = "localhost";
$bd_user = "xxx";
$bd_pass = "xxx";
$bd_nombre = "xxx";

$con = new mysqli($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_pass, $bd_nombre);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
   die('Conexion fallida [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$tbl_nombre  = 'tu_tabla';
$respaldoSQL = 'respaldo/tu_tabla.sql'; 
$query = "select * into outfile '$respaldoSQL' FROM $tbl_nombre";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
```

En 'respaldo/tu_tabla.sql' (debes especificar la ruta donde se guardará el archivo con extensión .sql)

Comment: Gracias por la aportación, sin embargo tu respuesta fue reportada como "baja calidad" , es importante leer [answer] para que realices respuestas correctamente en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: Por qué es de baja calidad @Jorgesys ?

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara revisa la primera edición, de hecho no creo que esto responda a la pregunta.

Comment: Ha si es verdad, no me había fijado.